# Python: how to write code that looks nicely and works with argparse or optparse?

Tags: python, coding-style, jython, argparse, optparse

I have to parse arguments so I used `argparse` module. This works well with Python 3.3 and Python 2.7. But some time I have to use it with Jython, and the last stable version of Jython is 2.5.3. This version do not have `argparse` module so I used older `optparse` module:

```
args = None
try:
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-u", "--url", action="store", dest="url", default=url, help='test script URL like "http://127.0.0.1/isof/hdb_ver_xml.hdb" or "hdb://127.0.0.1/isof/hdb_ver_xml.hdb"')
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--threads", action="store", type=int, dest="threads_cnt", default=threads_cnt, help='threads count')
    parser.add_argument("-T", "--timeout", action="store", type=int, dest="timeout_minutes", default=timeout_minutes, help='timeout in minutes')
    args = parser.parse_args()
except:
    import optparse
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-u", "--url", action="store", dest="url", default=url, help='test script URL like "http://127.0.0.1/isof/hdb_ver_xml.hdb" or "hdb://127.0.0.1/isof/hdb_ver_xml.hdb"')
    parser.add_option("-t", "--threads", action="store", type=int, dest="threads_cnt", default=threads_cnt, help='threads count')
    parser.add_option("-T", "--timeout", action="store", type=int, dest="timeout_minutes", default=timeout_minutes, help='timeout in minutes')
    args, _ = parser.parse_args()
return args
```

For me this code looks ugly because any change must be in 2 places. Of course I can use something like:

```
OPT_THREADS_HELP = 'threads count'
...
... help=OPT_THREADS_HELP
```

which will help a little but maybe there is nicer way of writing such code. Any idea?

Comment: I fear your best option is to use `optparse` *only*; it is still available in Python 3.3 and 3.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered storing your arguments separately?

```
 args = [{"args":("-u", "--url"), 
          "kwargs": {"action": "store", "dest": "url", "default": url, 
                     "help": 'test script URL like "http://127.0.0.1/isof/hdb_ver_xml.hdb" or "hdb://127.0.0.1/isof/hdb_ver_xml.hdb"'}
         }, ...]
```

Then whichever library you use, you can call:

```
try:
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    for arg in args:
        parser.add_argument(*arg['args'], **arg['kwargs'])
except:
    import optparse
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    for arg in args:
        parser.add_option(*arg['args'], **arg['kwargs'])
```

You could simplify further, allowing you to reduce the code in the `try` block, by using the bound method separately:

```
try:
    import argparse
except ImportError:
    import optparse
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    add_func = parser.add_option
else:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    add_func = parser.add_argument

for arg in args:
    add_func(*arg["args"], **arg["kwargs"])
```

Comment: That was something I was thinking about. Thanks. It will be useful for other than argparse<->optparse API changes.

Comment: You don't have to instantiate the parser inside the `try` block - you can just assign the `add_func` in to class variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using a 3rd party library, I would suggestion you try docopt:

That how you do thing there:

```
"""Naval Fate.

Usage:
  naval_fate.py ship new <name>...
  naval_fate.py ship <name> move <x> <y> [--speed=<kn>]
  naval_fate.py ship shoot <x> <y>
  naval_fate.py mine (set|remove) <x> <y> [--moored | --drifting]
  naval_fate.py (-h | --help)
  naval_fate.py --version

Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  --version     Show version.
  --speed=<kn>  Speed in knots [default: 10].
  --moored      Moored (anchored) mine.
  --drifting    Drifting mine.

"""
from docopt import docopt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='Naval Fate 2.0')
    print(arguments)
```

See [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt)

> docopt is tested with Python 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3 and PyPy.

[Docopt is also successfully used with Jython](https://github.com/docopt/docopt/pull/89)!

Comment: Does `docopt` support Jython, though?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I assumed that jython supports all Python 2.5 code... It's worth a try, because Docopt is really easy to use as you see.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Docopt is already used with Jython, check the link I posted.

Comment: Nice to know such powerful library. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to stick to just **one** command-line argument parsing library.

`optparse` is still available in Python 3.3 and 3.4, and no announcement has been made yet when it will be removed, if ever. Yes, it is deprecated and won't receive new versions, but it still *works* just fine.

When you need to support such a wide range of Python versions, don't try to duplicate work. If your needs are met by `optparse`, use *just* `optparse`.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes you must backport your code to older version of API/Python etc. I started with `argparse`. Of course I forget to try to just use standalone `argparse` with Jython.

Comment: But why try to keep two libraries, still? You could have *replaced* `argparse` with `optparse`. Why support both?

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign the parser class to a variable and monkey patch `OptionParser` to have `add_argument`.

Like this:

```
try:
    import argparse
    Parser = argparse.ArgumentParser
except ImportError:
    import optparse
    Parser = optparse.OptionParser
    Parser.add_argument = Parser.add_option


parser = Parser()
parser.add_argument("-u", "--url", action="store", dest="url", default=url, help='test script URL like "http://127.0.0.1/isof/hdb_ver_xml.hdb" or "hdb://127.0.0.1/isof/hdb_ver_xml.hdb"')
parser.add_argument("-t", "--threads", action="store", type=int, dest="threads_cnt",default=threads_cnt, help='threads count')
parser.add_argument("-T", "--timeout", action="store", type=int, dest="timeout_minutes", default=timeout_minutes, help='timeout in minutes')

args, _ = parser.parse_args()
```